# do i need to pass in all classes to be bound in JAXBContext before marshalling

Tags: java, xml, class, jaxb

I am working on a project where I need to retrieve a json object from the server and convert it xml format.

Now, currently it is working fine but I want to make sure that I am doing it the right way.

I have these java classes that are supposed to be bound.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

@XmlElement
private String status;

@XmlElement
private String details;

//getters and setters
}


@XmlRootElement
public class Response extends Message {

@XmlElement
private List<Case> cases;

//getters and setters
}


@XmlRootElement
public class Case {

@XmlElement
private id;

@XmlElement
private name;

//gettersand setters
}
```

Now this is what I did in my action class which works fine: Notice that I passed in all the classes i want to bind.

```
public class StrutsAction {

public execute() {
    //initial logic

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class, Message.class, Case.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller(); 
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(reponse, sw);
    return new  ByteArrayInputStream(sw.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
}
```

I tried to do it this way, and it still works: Here I just pass ed in the Response.class

```
public class StrutsAction {

public execute() {
    //initial logic

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller(); 
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(reponse, sw);
    return new  ByteArrayInputStream(sw.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
}
```

Now, in my actual project I have a lot more classes to be bound and I don't want to pass in all the classes when I call JAXBContext.newInstance(class...) if possible. So can someone tell me the best way to do this. When should I pass in all the classes to be bound. I have not totally understood what it says on the documentation.

I added this helper method that generates the response to make my code cleaner:

```
public static InputStream generateSuccessMsgResponse(Object object, Class<?>...classes) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller(); 
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(object, sw);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(sw.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (PropertyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

but then whenever i call it i still have to pass in all binding classes:

```
public String execute() {
inputStream = MethodUtil.generateSuccessMsgResponse(ResponseObj, Response.class, Message.class, Case.class, OtherClass.class, AnotherClass.class);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

So my real question is do i have to pass in all those classes? coz if I just pass in the Response.class, it works just the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can get object's class and pass it to JAXBConext. Something like this:

```
    public static String unparse(Object object, String encoding) throws JAXBException, SQLException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, encoding);        
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(object, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
```

Usage:

```
    public void execute() { 
        String messageXml = unparse(messageObject, "UTF-8");
        String responseXml = unparse(responseObject, "UTF-8");
        String caseXml = unparse(caseObject, "UTF-8");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but notice that I added more code snippets with my existing helper method, the only thing I am really confused about is if I can just pass in one class (in the case of example above, the response class) when calling the helper method instead of all the classes im trying to marshal

Comment: In my code that works in production i don't need to pass all dependent classes to marshaller.

Comment: yeah it does work without passing in all dependent classes. but i am not sure if there are downsides for doing such thing